# iPhone + access Controls from other class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, access-modifiers

I have classes: `PropertyCalcViewController` .m & .h

In the .h I have

```
IBOutlet UIButton *btnGo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *btnGo;
```

and in the .m file I have

```
@synthesize *btnGo;
```

Now I also have another class `Manager` .m & .h.

What I want to do is that access `btnGo` from the `Manager` class and remove it from `PropertyCalcViewController` like

```
[btnGo removeFromSuperView]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a property, you use the "dot-syntax":

```
[the_view_ctrler.btnGo removeFromSuperview];
```

Also, I believe you mean `@synthesize btnGo;`, instead of `@synthesize *btnGo;` which is a syntax-error.

Comment: the_manager is the object of Manager class ?
btnGo is in PropertyCalcViewController class not in Manager class..

Comment: Oh I see. Your description isn't that clear because the `@interface` is missing.

Comment: the_view_ctrler is the object of PropertyCalcViewController class ?

Comment: OK, I did that but the button is not getting removed :(

Comment: @pratik: Have you changed your `@synthesize`?

Comment: @KennyTM: Yes I have changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Insure that btnGo has been properly linked up in Interface Builder.  Simple but common oversight.